# objective c mapkit click button in annotation

Tags: objective-c, annotations, mapkit

Hi i have a map view page in my app where i display 200 + markers.

I initiate these at present with

```
MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:currentobjectarray.title andCoordinate:location];
```

These produces a text label when the marker is clicked.  How can i add a button to the annotation view so that when it is clicked i can navigate to a "more info" page for the selected marker?.  Its the button part i am not sure of.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: You need to use a custom annotation view.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `UIButton` and assign it to the `rightCalloutAccessoryView` property of your MKAnnotationView.

In the `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` method, where your are returning you custom `MKAnnotationView` instance, insert this code to create a button and associate it with an action.

I assumed that your `MKAnnotationView` instance is called `annotationView` and that your method to be called is `presentMoreInfo`.

```
UIButton * disclosureButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[disclosureButton addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(presentMoreInfo)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = disclosureButton;
```

Your `presentMoreInfo` method can be something like

```
- (void)presentMoreInfo {
    DetailsViewController * detailsVC = [DetailsViewController new];

    //configure your view controller
    //...

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsVC animated:YES];
}
```